# Mac OSX: How to associate a directory as bundle

Tags: macos, bundle, osx-mavericks, directory-structure

I am writing an app for Maverick.
The app creates a folder under /user/document, named "folder.db".
All the user related files will be in a folder "folder.db".
I would like to associate my app with "folder.db" directly, so that clicking on it would open my app and not the Finder.

How to achieve that?

Note: I tried to play with the UTI settings in xcode but not luck...

Answer (score 0):

First .db is generally used for databases. So probably not a good idea. What you are looking for is a package or bundle in Cocoa terms. In Cocoa you want to look for the fileWrapper methods. Those create package/bundle files that are folders with a special flag bit set to make it act like an opaque file in Finder

You might want to study NSWorkSpace, NSFileManager, NSBundle, NSDocument and NSOpenPanel and NSSavePanel. 
Those will get you on the path.

Comment: thanks, the .db is just an example... :-)
I went through the docs but  I have in place already a sort of filesystem structure and creating a file wrapper would modify all the file references...
Is there any way to assign to a directory the attribute of a bundle/wrapper or to register the directory name a bundle in OSX?